# Java: Using a for-loop to fill in an array with random integers within a specific range

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, random

> Criticism is welcome! I'm learning and wish to be corrected so that I
>   may learn!

How would I go about using a `for-loop` to generate a `random values` to fill an `array` within the range of something like 1 to 50.

I have it set up to fill an array with however many numbers the user wishes for it to fill. I'm currently just playing around with arrays trying to understand how to use them in different ways. I know I'll have a test coming up where I'll have to do something similar and would like to have mastered it.

This is what I have so far... but I'd like to fill it with `random integers` in a range (any range), but for the sake of giving a range for learning purposes lets just go with 1-50.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

{public static void main(String [] args)
   {
     Scanner MyScan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int Number;
     System.out.println("How many integers do you want in your array?");
     Number = MyScan.nextInt();
     int[] MyArray = new int[Number];

    }//end main
}//end class
```

Comment: Criticism is welcome: please stick to the Java-standard naming; variables should start with a lowercase character.

Comment: Thank you @RobAu I will do that. I'm still learning all the rules. I appreciate it! I'll be sure to remember that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Random r = new Random();
int Low = 10;
int High = 100;

for(int i = 0; i < MyArray .length; i++){
        MyArray [i]  = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @jipr311 I couldn't find anything that was clear enough without trying to decipher other peoples code. I appreciate it!